# PBEWITHSHA1AND128BITAES-CBC-BC Algorithm - must be 16 bytes Long error

Tags: java, cryptography, encryption

I have a PSKC XML file, that contains my Salt/Key, IV(Initialization
Vector), Encrypted Data, and password.

Now, I am trying to Do Password Based Encyption and Decryption using the `PBEWITHSHA1AND128BITAES-CBC-BC` Algorithm.

It works if I generate salt and IV randomly.

However, it fails if i don't generate it randomly. Instead of generating Salt and IV randomly, I am using my own salt, IV, password and everything.

Here is my code:

```
    /**
    * parts of this code were copied from the StandardPBEByteEncryptor class from
    * the Jasypt (www.jasypt.org) project
    */
    public class AESCrypt
    {
    private final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "PBEWITHSHA1AND128BITAES-CBC-BC";
    // private final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC";
    private final String MODE_PADDING = "/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private final int DEFAULT_SALT_SIZE_BYTES = 128;
    private byte[] ivParamSpec1 = 
           {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    private final SecureRandom rand;
    private final String passwd = "kn4\"bE,W11kewsUd";
    public AESCrypt() throws Exception
    {
    rand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    }
    private byte[] generateSalt(int size)
    {
    byte[] salt = new byte[size];
    rand.nextBytes(salt);
    return salt;
    }
    private SecretKey generateKey(String algorithm, int keySize, byte[] salt)
    throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    InvalidKeySpecException
    {
    // SecretKeySpec Spec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, algorithm);
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passwd.toCharArray(), salt,100000);
    SecretKey tmpKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keySize / 8];
    SecretKeySpec Spec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, algorithm);
    System.arraycopy(tmpKey.getEncoded(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
    System.out.println("SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, algorithm)---->"+Spec);
    return Spec;
    }
    private byte[] generateIV(Cipher cipher)
    {
    byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    rand.nextBytes(iv);
    return iv;
    }
    private byte[] appendArrays(byte[] firstArray, byte[] secondArray)
    {
    final byte[] result = new byte[firstArray.length + secondArray.length];
    System.arraycopy(firstArray, 0, result, 0, firstArray.length);
    System.arraycopy(secondArray, 0, result, firstArray.length, secondArray.length);
    return result;
    }
    public byte[] encrypt(String algorithm, int keySize, final byte[] message)
    throws Exception
    {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm + MODE_PADDING);
    // The salt size for the chosen algorithm is set to be equal
    // to the algorithm's block size (if it is a block algorithm).
    int saltSizeBytes = DEFAULT_SALT_SIZE_BYTES;
    int algorithmBlockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
    if (algorithmBlockSize > 0)
    {
    saltSizeBytes = algorithmBlockSize;
    }
    // Create salt
    // final byte[] salt = generateSalt(saltSizeBytes);
    final byte[] salt = "EW0h0yUcDX72WU9UiKiCwDpXsJg=".getBytes();
    SecretKey key = generateKey(algorithm, keySize, salt);
    // create a new IV for each encryption
    // final IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec();
    ivParamSpec1 = "ixYgnjjY58RNacxZHwxgBQ==".getBytes();
    final IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivParamSpec1);
    // Perform encryption using the Cipher
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParamSpec);
    byte[] encryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(message);
    // append the IV and salt
    encryptedMessage = appendArrays(ivParamSpec.getIV(), encryptedMessage);
    encryptedMessage = appendArrays(salt, encryptedMessage);
    return encryptedMessage;
    }
    public byte[] decrypt(String algorithm, int keySize, final byte[] encryptedMessage) throws Exception
    {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm + MODE_PADDING);
    // determine the salt size for the first layer of encryption
    int saltSizeBytes = DEFAULT_SALT_SIZE_BYTES;
    int algorithmBlockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
    if (algorithmBlockSize > 0)
    {
    saltSizeBytes = algorithmBlockSize;
    }
    System.out.println("saltSizeBytes:" + saltSizeBytes);
    byte[] decryptedMessage = new byte[encryptedMessage.length];
    System.arraycopy(encryptedMessage, 0, decryptedMessage, 0,
    encryptedMessage.length);
    // extract the salt and IV from the incoming message
    byte[] salt = null;
    byte[] iv = null;
    byte[] encryptedMessageKernel = null;
    final int saltStart = 0;
    final int saltSize = (saltSizeBytes < decryptedMessage.length ? saltSizeBytes
    : decryptedMessage.length);
    // final int saltSize = 32;
    // System.out.println("saltSize:"+saltSize);
    final int ivStart = (saltSizeBytes < decryptedMessage.length ? saltSizeBytes
    : decryptedMessage.length);
    final int ivSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
    final int encMesKernelStart = (saltSizeBytes + ivSize < decryptedMessage.length ? saltSizeBytes
    + ivSize
    : decryptedMessage.length);
    final int encMesKernelSize = (saltSizeBytes + ivSize < decryptedMessage.length ? (decryptedMessage.length
    - saltSizeBytes - ivSize)
    : 0);
    salt = new byte[saltSize];
    iv = new byte[ivSize];
    System.out.println("saltSize:" + saltSize);
    System.out.println("ivSize:" + ivSize);
    encryptedMessageKernel = new byte[encMesKernelSize];
    System.out.println("encryptedMessageKernel");
    System.arraycopy(decryptedMessage, saltStart, salt, 0, saltSize);
    System.arraycopy(decryptedMessage, ivStart, iv, 0, ivSize);
    System.arraycopy(decryptedMessage, encMesKernelStart,
    encryptedMessageKernel, 0, encMesKernelSize);
    SecretKey key = generateKey(algorithm, keySize, salt);
    System.out.println("ekey");
    ivParamSpec1 = "ixYgnjjY58RNacxZHwxgBQ==".getBytes();
    IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivParamSpec1);
    // Perform decryption using the Cipher
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivParamSpec);
    decryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(encryptedMessageKernel);
    // Return the results
    return decryptedMessage;
    }
    private byte[] decryptWithLWCrypto(byte[] cipher, String password, byte[] salt, final int iterationCount)
    throws Exception
    {
    PKCS12ParametersGenerator pGen = new PKCS12ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
    char[] passwordChars = password.toCharArray();
    final byte[] pkcs12PasswordBytes = PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS12PasswordToBytes(passwordChars);
    pGen.init(pkcs12PasswordBytes, salt, iterationCount);
    CBCBlockCipher aesCBC = new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine());
    ParametersWithIV aesCBCParams = (ParametersWithIV) pGen.generateDerivedParameters(256, 128);
    aesCBC.init(false, aesCBCParams);
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aesCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(aesCBC,new PKCS7Padding());
    byte[] plainTemp = new byte[aesCipher.getOutputSize(cipher.length)];
    int offset = aesCipher.processBytes(cipher, 0, cipher.length, plainTemp, 0);
    int last = aesCipher.doFinal(plainTemp, offset);
    final byte[] plain = new byte[offset + last];
    System.arraycopy(plainTemp, 0, plain, 0, plain.length);
    System.out.println("Plain--->"+plain);
    return plain;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    AESCrypt aesCrypt = new AESCrypt();
    String originalText = "6skYngWZxkTgsRIoFPLS1mpI32Q=";
    String toDecrypt = new String(Base64.encode(aesCrypt.encrypt("AES", 128, originalText.getBytes())));
    System.out.println("Original Data----->"+originalText);
    System.out.println("After Encrpytion--->"+toDecrypt);
    byte[] criptata = Base64.decode(toDecrypt);
    byte[] decriptata = aesCrypt.decrypt("AES", 128, criptata);
    String msgdecriptato = new String(decriptata);
    System.out.println("After Decrption--->"+msgdecriptato);
    if (!originalText.equals(msgdecriptato))
    {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Strings do not match!");
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("Matched.....");
    }
    // byte[] cipher = "RVcwaDB5VWNEWDcyV1U5VWlLaUN3RHBYc0pnPWl4WWduampZNThSTmFjeFoJfgJbigcnDs0TJdNu7yEkprlJFdilLrLJT8uoQ3dm/A==".getBytes();
    // String password = "kn4\"bE,W11kewsUd";
    // byte[] salt = "EW0h0yUcDX72WU9UiKiCwDpXsJg=".getBytes();
    // System.out.println(aesCrypt.decryptWithLWCrypto(cipher, password, salt , 128));
    }
    }
    When I try to run this... Am getting following Errors,
    Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.a(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at AESCrypt.encrypt(AESCrypt.java:113)
    at AESCrypt.main(AESCrypt.java:213)
```

I can't truncate the salt size or IV size, then there will not be any data integrity.

Even if i truncate my IV size to 16 bytes from 28 bytes, it works for encryption, but it doesn't work for decryption. It produces the following errors:

```
   Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
at AESCrypt.decrypt(AESCrypt.java:163)
at AESCrypt.main(AESCrypt.java:178)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you improve the formatting of your post?  Which line throws the exception?

Comment: I did try to salvage this gibberish into something that can be comprehended, but failed. Moron edits undid all my work, please don't edit posts if you don't know English. Vote to close, beyond repair.

Comment: I agree.  The formatting is irredeemable.  OP - if you want people to take your Questions seriously, you need to format / indent them code and the stack traces properly.  It is *unreasonable* to expect other people to do that for you.  And it is *unreasonable* to expect people to read reams of badly formatted code.